How to correctly remove the gradle wrapper from VCS?
I don't want to commit the gradle wrapper to VCS¹. Which gradle files could be git-ignored so other users have the least troubles setting up their environment? I'm specifically wondering about gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties which may or may not be useful, since it seems to hold the URL to the distribution and its version.
Here's my current gitignore:
/gradlew
/gradlew.bat
/gradle/wrapper/*
!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties # not sure about this

Does it look right?
¹ Why?
(not relevant, but I anticipate answers beside the point, I'm not looking to negociate)
Even though it is recommended by the Gradle team themselves, comitting the wrapper to VCS sounds like a really bad idea:

Binary files could hide malware (the xzorcist/CVE-2024-3094 exploit used an archive to hide its payload)
This file take unreclaimable space, when it could just be downloaded from elsewhere, like all other project dependencies or the JDK itself
It doesn't make builds more reproducible than what other package managers do with their package-lock.json or Cargo.lock (download URL + checksum), I don't understand this argument from the Gradle team
The JDK is crucial to develop a Java project too, yet we don't push it to VCS. Same goes for the gradle dependencies themselves, most people don't vendor them, for good reasons.


You don't need to keep the gradle.properties file if you have specified a desired version in build.gradle like:
// build.gradle.kts

tasks.wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "7.6"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

So when you/teammate call gradle wrapper, the gradle.properties will be generated with specified version.
Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

It depends what your alternative strategy is for new developers to work with the project, and for existing developers to inherit changes to the Gradle setup.
It sounds like your proposal is that everyone has a local copy of the wrapper on their machine. In that case you need a pre-defined method for everyone to create the same wrapper.
That method can either use a pre-existing gradle-wrapper.properties file (in which case you need it), or it creates a new one from scratch (in which case you don't).
I suggest that the cleanest approach is to define a route to creating the wrapper that doesn't use that file: then you can .gitignore it.
Such a route could be defining a Wrapper task to be run by new developers, and also by existing developers on a Gradle setup change. If you take that route, I think you would want to find a consistent way to ensure such a wrapper task is run as and when needed, perhaps by failing the build if the Gradle version is incorrect.
